# Error during exporting result to Excel using SQL Agent

Tags: sql-server, ssis, export-to-excel, sql-agent-job, ssms-2012

I'm using SSMS 2012. I'm using Export wizard to run a script and export it to an Excel file. I'm saving this as a SSIS package in SQL server. Then, I try to schedule a job using SQL Agent to execute this SSIS package. I schedule it as a recurring job. The job gets executed successfully the first time exporting the result to the Excel file. But, after that the job gets failed with the error message destination file already exists.
How do I overcome this error? Also, I don't want the result to be over-written. I want to have the results either as different excel files or different spreadsheets in the same excel file.

Comment: SSIS can't append to Excel files unfortunately. You could however alter the SSIS package and make the output-filename date depended to something like the following for example: `OutputFilename_yyyymmdd_hhmmss.xlsx`

Answer (score 0):

As Nicky rightly pointed out, SSIS doesn't append to excel files with the out-of-the box package that you have obtained by the using the Export feature. You would need to tweak that package further for your requirements if you need output in multiple sheets within the same excel.

One of the first things that you would need to ensure is, have logic in place to only get the latest data in each run of your package. This you can do either by having to select records greater than last package execution time/ max Id or any of such filters. Post that you would have to have a script task that would create a worksheet/table dynamically during each run and have your results populated in the destination worksheet.

This following link should help you achieve it - http://www.bidn.com/blogs/KeithHyer/bidn-blog/2512/creating-excel-worksheets-dynamically-in-ssis

Answer (score 0):

Following tutorial explains how to dynamically create excel using SSIS.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwUhHIpRoIA